# Freestyle swimming: Where to breath in (chest vs. stomach)?

Tags: swimming, breathing, chest, stomach, technique

Everyone just talks about inhaling, but no one ever specifies whether to breath in your **chest** (shallow breathing, clavicular breathing, thoracic breathing), your **stomach** (Diaphragmatic breathing, abdominal breathing, belly breathing), or maybe both.

- Does one of these techniques have an advantage over the other?
- Is there consensus about which technique to use?
- If so, why?

Comment: You are swimming, which is an exertion. When you exert yourself in exercise, do you want to take shallow breaths, or deep ones? I generally prefer deep breaths.

Comment: I don't know and would like to learn it the correct way. At the moment, I take shallow breaths as it's easier, but very often I read (e.g. when it comes to running) that diaphragmatic breathing has some advantages - I just don't know whether it's the same for swimming. If so, then I'd like to learn this technique of course, but as it requires more training and readjustment, I want to be sure that it's worth the effort.

Comment: I agree with @JohnP - I want as much oxygen as I can get, and that means using the diaphragm to do what it does so well - bring in lots of air.

Comment: @JohnP I had always had the **bite of air** which is often referred to when swimming. To me it is just shallow. Moreover, I prefer to swim with my belly button pulled in (*slightly*) - which keep my leg together when kicking in freestyle